# Explicit invocation of systemd service does not take into account EnvironmentFile

Tags: systemd

I have the following `systemd` unit file

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service

[Unit]
Description = My Service

[Service]
ExecStart = /bin/sh -c 'exec /usr/local/bin/myservice [arguments] >>/var/log/myservice/log.log 2>>/var/log/myservice/err.log'
EnvironmentFile = /etc/myservice/config
User = someuser
Group = somegroup

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I am using the redirection format for logs given that my `systemd` is pretty old (`232`)

I want to invoke this service via `systemd run` so I am typing

```
sudo systemd-run myservice
Running as unit: run-rac9ffa945b374f2fa8a8273567427005.service
```

I see in my execution logs however that

a) `EnvironmentFile = /etc/myservice/config` is not taken into account at all

b) no logs are created in `/var/log/myservice/`

Do these issues make any sense?

Comment: Have you tried without `ExecStart = /bin/sh -c 'exec`? Just `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myservice` and see if environment variables are loaded in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`systemd-run` does not start the service specified in `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service`, it just runs `/usr/local/bin/myservice` in a transient unit, that's why the unit is called `run-rac9ffa945b374f2fa8a8273567427005.service`, not `myservice.service`.

To run `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service`, use `systemctl start myservice.service` (after running `systemctl daemon-reload` if you have just written the unit file).